# Try to get average value from Android Room Persistence Library with dynamic conditions

Tags: android, android-room

I am trying to get average value if two conditions using Android Room Persistence Library, my entity looks like this:

```
public class FinishedTask {
    private static final String TASK_NAME_COLUMN = "taskName";
    private static final String DEPARTMENT_NAME_COLUMN = "departmentName";
    private static final String EMPLOYEE_NAME_COLUMN = "employeeName";
    private static final String TIME_UNTIL_DOME_NAME_COLUMN = "timeUntilDoneName";
    private static final String SAVED_DATE_NAME_COLUMN = "savedDateName";

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    private long id = 0;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "passedMilliseconds")
    private long passedMilliseconds = 0;

    @ColumnInfo(name = TASK_NAME_COLUMN)
    private String  taskName = TASK_NAME_COLUMN;

    @ColumnInfo(name = DEPARTMENT_NAME_COLUMN)
    private String departmentName = DEPARTMENT_NAME_COLUMN;

    @ColumnInfo(name = EMPLOYEE_NAME_COLUMN)
    private String employeeName = EMPLOYEE_NAME_COLUMN;

    @ColumnInfo(name = TIME_UNTIL_DOME_NAME_COLUMN)
    private long timeUntilDone = 0;


    @ColumnInfo(name = SAVED_DATE_NAME_COLUMN)
    private long savedDate = 0;

    public FinishedTask(){}
}
```

My Query looks like this:

```
@Query("SELECT AVG(timeUntilDoneName) FROM finishedTasks WHERE :column1=:value1 AND :column2=:value2")
Single<Long> getAverageTime(String column1, String value1, String column2, String value2);
```

And I got error:

> Query returned empty result set: SELECT AVG(timeUntilDoneName) FROM finishedTasks WHERE ?=? AND ?=?

When I change query to:

```
@Query("SELECT AVG(timeUntilDoneName) FROM finishedTasks WHERE taskName=:value1 AND :departmentName=:value2")
Single<Long> getAverageTime(String value1, String value2);
```

Everything works fine and as expected. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the last time I tried room it was not supporting dynamic column names.

Comment: Am I doing something wrong in my queries?

Comment: `:column1=:value1 AND :column2=:value2"` columns can't be dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use placeholders where SQLite itself supports placeholders, and SQLite does not support replacing column names with placeholders.